# How can I receive data shared from another iOS app, eg. WhatsApp?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I can find the ways to receive and handle shared Text/Data on Xamarin.Android how can the same be done on Xamarin.iOS?

When you share something on WhatsApp I want my app to show up here:
[image]

Then I need to handle the data. I really cannot find many answers to this, some say it can't be done using xamarin. Others want to rely on WhatsApp's API. The rest use Swift or Java where I need C#.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is iOS Share Extension and can be done on Xamarin.iOS
There is a detailed document here for all other iOS Extensions since iOS 8 with a short video. A tutorial for Today Extension but the creation of Share Extension is similar.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/extensions

You can look at the Xamarin.iOS sample code for Share extension (which meets your issue: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios8/Share/

Comment: Thanks you so much Tri! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @TylerByte I am happy to hear that it solved your problem. Please mark my post as the Answer then.

Comment: Very sorry still very new to this. Complete.